# Intercept close Popup from Parent Page

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a question.
In an html page, I have javascript code that allows me to open and close a popup window by clicking on a link displayed in the link, so the text displayed in the link changes to the state of the popup window (open-closed).

With a variable true / false I manage the opening and closing of the popup window to 
click on a link whose text is aligned "opened popup" / "closed popup".

The next step is to make this same change in state (true / false, "opened popup" / "close popup") directly by closing the popup window.
The idea is to not have to refresh the page.
Is this possible?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 1):

Handle the popup `window` object's `unload` event.

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your answer.
I try to use unload event, but this event runs (if I remember correctly) in each case, and interferes with others javascript operations on the parent page.